# Extract string with digits and special characters in r

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a list of filenames in the format `"filename PID00-00-00"` or just `"PID00-00-00"`.
I want to extract part of the filename to create an `ID` column.

I am currently using this code for the string extraction

```
names(df) <- stringr::str_extract(names(df), "(?<=PID)\\d+")

binded1 = rbindlist(df, idcol = "ID")%>%
  as.data.frame(binded1)
```

This gives the `ID` as the first set of digits after PID. e.g. `filename PID1234-00-01` becomes ID `1234`.

I want to also extract the first hyphen and following digits. So from `filename PID1234-00-01` I want `1234-00`.

What should my `regex` be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
stringr::str_extract(names(df),"(?<=PID)\\d{4}-\\d{2}")
```

Comment: I used `"(?<=PID)\\d+-\\d+"` as there are various numbers of digits before and after the hyphen